# Consulta en SQL que devuelve un valor predeterminado en caso de no encontrar coincidencia

Tags: mysql, sql

En MySQL quiero realizar la siguiente consulta de manera eficiente. Supongamos que tenemos una tabla `A` con columnas `id` y `C`. Quiero hacer una query que sea algo como:

```
SELECT C FROM A WHERE id IN ([valores del id])
```

Y que en el caso que el id no este en la tabla `A` devuelva por ejemplo un `1`. Además quiero que devuelva los resultados manteniendo el orden con el que le han sido dados los ids en el `IN`.

Sin mantener el orden se que puedo hacer:

```
Select de las que si existen
Union all
Select de las que no existe
```

Pero esto no me sirve puesto que no mantiene el orden y no se me ocurre ninguna manera de añadirle algo a la query para que siga manteniendo el orden.

Edit: Como han preguntado por la query con la que hice el intento la comparto:

```sql
SELECT C 
FROM A 
WHERE ID IN (
008,01048,01058,01088,01098,01108,01118,01128,01138,01148,01168,
01178,01188,01198,01208,01228,01238,01248,01258,01268,01278,
01288,01298,01318,01328,01338,01358,01368,01418,01508,01518,
01528,01538,01548,01558,01568,01578,01588,01598,01608,01618,
01628,01638,01648,01658,01668,01678,01688,01698,01708,01718
) ORDER BY FIELD(
ID,008,01048,01058,01088,01098,01108,01118,01128,01138,01148,
01168,01178,01188,01198,01208,01228,01238,01248,01258,01268,
01278,01288,01298,01318,01328,01338,01358,01368,01418,01508,
01518,01528,01538,01548,01558,01568,01578,01588,01598,01608,
01618,01628,01638,01648,01658,01668,01678,01688,01698,01708,01718)
```

Con esta primera query obtendria los resultados (que si se encuentran en la tabla, aquellos que no, pues simplemente serán omitidos por la salida) ordenados por el orden del in (es decir el `C` associado al `008` me apareciera el primero luego el del `01048`, etc). Que esten ordenados "númericamente" es pura casualidad y no es un invariante de la consulta así que no puede ser asumido.

Si ayuda en algo esta query es ejecutada por un server en typeORM, pero en principio usando la opción de ejecutar queries directamente del typeORM no debería haber ninguna diferencia en que un humano ejecutase la misma query en un SQL.

Edit 2: Haciendo caso a la recomendación de @David JP añado a la pregunta la información que redacte en el comentario.

Porque uso este orden?

Muy resumidamente la tabla A es una tabla con precios relacionada con otra tabla B de productos, una query obtiene los ids de los productos más probables de ser los que buscaba el usuario y los ordena por la probabilidad de que sean estos, la función de la probabilidad es algo compleja y aunque la compartiera (que prefiero que no por si acaso) me da la sensación que no haría nada óptima la query

Comment: ¿Y cómo has intentado resolverlo? Para que podamos ayudarte, debes compartir tus intentos

Comment: ¿Para qué podrías querer los id en un orden determinado?

Comment: nos puedes explicar cuál es el orden que usas? No se puede con un orden arbitrario, pero si el orden de los ID obedece por ejemplo a un ordenamiento racional, o es el orden en que figuran en otra tabla, sí se puede

Comment: @ffflabs Muy resumidamente la tabla A es una tabla con precios relacionada con otra tabla B de productos, una query obtiene los ids de los productos más probables de ser los que buscaba el usuario y los ordena por la probabilidad de que sean estos, la función de la probabilidad es algo compleja y aunque la compartiera (que prefiero que no por si acaso) me da la sensación que no haría nada óptima la query

Comment: @DavidJP He editado el comentario y he puesto la query que usaba para obtener los que si que estaban en orden Obviamente, la query para obtener los que no estaban daba igual el orden puesto que no podriá distinguirlos, ya que simplemente devuelve un valor por defecto para todos.

Comment: Mírate la funcion IFNULL de mysql 
SELECT IFNULL(C, 1) FROM A WHERE.....

Comment: @5n10m Según he podido ver en internet el IFNULL solo sirve si la línea ya existiera en la tabla A y el valor almacenado en la columna C fueran nulo. Si la línea no existe no sirve.

Comment: ¿Por qué no manejarlo en la [*Capa de Negocio*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_multicapa#Capas_y_niveles)?

Comment: as intentando un `if else` o un `case else` o un `coalesce`? para los valores nulos, y el orden puedes hacer un order by 1; donde uno es la primera columna seleccionada!

Comment: @Sal Efectivamente esto esta en la capa de negocio, puesto que es el TypeORM el que envia la query a la BDD donde se ejecuta, de todas formas entiendo que te refieres a obtener solo aquellos que si existan y luego guardar un valor predeterminado a los que no. No quiero hacer eso, ya que (si no me he equivocado al calcular los costes) eso tendria coste O(query) + O(n), donde n := # de ids, query := coste temporal de la query (no pongo nada porque en el caso de SQL no tengo muy claro como calcularlo) , y me gustaria poder hacerlo todo en una query.

Comment: @Bryro Buenas, el caso COALESCE lo descarto porque es lo mismo que un IFNULL, con el `CASE ELSE` no tengo mucha idea de como usar el case sin que sea un select, pero entonces vuelve a no servirme para los que no existan porque no va a encontrar . El que si parece prometedor es hacer algo como un IF SELECT ... IS NULL o algo así, lo mirare a ver si puedo encontrar algo que sirva

Comment: A reserva de que agregues un ejemplo del resultado esperado, solo necesitas un [OUTER JOIN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentencia_JOIN_en_SQL#Combinaci%C3%B3n_externa_(OUTER_JOIN)) con una *vista en linea* de los ids y su orden generado ya sea con una [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions) o [*variables de usuario*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Si la combinación externa es nula aplicas el valor predeterminado.

Comment: @Sal Buenas, si yo de momento lo he hecho con un outer join con la tabla donde estan los productos (donde ahí si que estan todos los ids y por eso el outer join funciona), y estaba esperando a ver si alguien daba alguna solución más óptima. No se lo suficiente de SQL para afirmar que tu solución es más óptima pero puedo afirmar que si funciona. Esperaré un par de días más a ver si alguien da una solución más óptima y en caso contrario crearé una respuesta con tu idea de consulta que aceptaré (a no ser que tu crees la tuya, en cuyo caso aceptare la tuya)

Comment: Si es algo como [esto](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ggDG9LhqCBzBBDCZbcjZkF/0) lo pongo como respuesta.

Comment: @Sal efectivamente

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ahora que veo que lo que quieres hacer, ya sé cómo hacerlo.

Empieza creando una tabla en la que almacenarás los índices en orden, bien de inserción o calculado con tu función de probabilidad:

```
CREATE TABLE ids_ordenados(
  orden_insercion int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id int,
  orden float
  );
```

Y después combina ambas tablas con un simple `JOIN`, que para eso está, ordenando por el criterio de los anteriores que prefieras:

```
SELECT C FROM A
  JOIN ids_ordenados USING(id)
  ORDER BY orden;
```

Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo los comentarios, que han resultado bastante clarificadores.

Comment: Buenas, es posible que me haya explicado algo mal y consecuentemente tu respuesta solo aborde el problema del orden (que entiendo que lo has puesto porque esta manera debe ser más eficiente que el FIELD que yo estaba usando) y no el problema de mostrar un valor por defecto cuando en la tabla "ids_ordenados" (que es realmente el tema que queria abordar con mi pregunta)